# Remove the object or item which I have in the json string format from javascript array named data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, associative-array

```
var item =  {"mtyp":2,"mtr":3,"qnt":51,"unt":"pint","nts":"cvbbcv"}

var data = [{"mtyp":"2","mtr":"2","qnt":"54","unt":"ml","nts":"ngvjn"},{"mtyp":"2","mtr":"3","qnt":"51","unt":"pint","nts":"cvbbcv"}]
```

output should be:

```
var data = [{"mtyp":"2","mtr":"2","qnt":"54","unt":"ml","nts":"ngvjn"}]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you for your response. Can you please tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: @SwarajGiri - Yes, I know it didn't really matter in this instance, it's just the principle of the thing after I've had to roll back too many other destructive edits to code in other questions. Regarding the six-character limit, perhaps you could've added an extra bit of non-code text, like "Input:", in parallel to the original "Output". Anyway, I'll delete my original comment now that you've seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below script that I have written to meet your requirement.
I am assuming that your JSON object will have similar key names at both end, if not then let me know I will update the script for you.

Your desired result will be available in resultdata.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var item = { "mtyp": 2, "mtr": 3, "qnt": 51, "unt": "pint", "nts": "cvbbcv" }

    var data = [{ "mtyp": "2", "mtr": "2", "qnt": "54", "unt": "ml", "nts": "ngvjn" }, { "mtyp": "2", "mtr": "3", "qnt": "51", "unt": "pint", "nts": "cvbbcv" }]

    // Holds the result data.
    var resultdata = [{}];

    // Remove initialized result set.
    resultdata.pop();

    // Variable to hold comparison value.
    var hasMatch = false;

    // Loop through data values.
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {

        // Fetch current item.
        var individualData = data[index];

        // Compare item values with individual data values.
        if (item.mtyp == individualData.mtyp &&
            item.mtr == individualData.mtr &&
            item.qnt == individualData.qnt &&
            item.unt == individualData.unt &&
            item.nts == individualData.nts) {
            hasMatch = true;
        }
        else {
            hasMatch = false;
        }

        // If then is no match then add to the result.
        // ResultData will hold all the values that are not present in item.
        if (!hasMatch)
        { resultdata.push(individualData); }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Dinesh for your response. Tried the same. It works, but the only problem is I am getting the output as `[{},{"mtyp":"2","mtr":"2","qnt":"54","unt":"ml","nts":"ngvjn"}]` instead I want  `[{"mtyp":"2","mtr":"2","qnt":"54","unt":"ml","nts":"ngvjn"}]`

Comment: I have updated the code, this will work for you. Do mark as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is quite unclear, if you like to get a new array or an in situ (in place) solution, and despite some values does not match type wise, like

```
qnt: 51
```

and

```
qnt: "51"
```

I suggest to use a combination of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the array itself and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for checking all properties and get all items who not match.

```js
var item = { mtyp: 2, mtr: 3, qnt: 51, unt: "pint", nts: "cvbbcv" },
    data = [{ mtyp: "2", mtr: "2", qnt: "54", unt: "ml", nts: "ngvjn" }, { mtyp: "2", mtr: "3", qnt: "51", unt: "pint", nts: "cvbbcv" }];

data = data.filter(function (a) {
    return !Object.keys(item).every(function (k) {
        return a[k] == item[k];
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina for your reply. The code is short & works perfect!